# Ideolog (PyCharm): how to configure log format for standard logging library

Tags: logging, pycharm

I am using standard Python logging library (`import logging`) and install Ideolog plugin. But it doesn't support format of standard logging library (and PyCharm asks to configure it). I have tried some regex, but they don't fit. How should I configure it?

[image: Screen of log format and Ideolog error]

[image: Default Ideolog settings]

PS In code I use logging like `logging.info('Some info')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had the same issue.

I used the following config:

My logging format looks like this:

```
"%(asctime)s %(name)-30s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"
```

Log Parsing Pattern:

```
pattern="^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s(\S*)\s*(\w*)\s*(.*)$" timePattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" linePattern="^\d" timeId="0" severityId="2" fullmatch="true"
```

Log Hightlight Patterns:

```
pattern="^\s*ERROR?\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="-65536" stripe="true"
pattern="^\s*WARNING?\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="-22016" bold="true"
pattern="^\s*INFO\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="-12599489"
pattern="^\s*DEBUG\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="-14927361" stripe="true"
pattern="^\s*CRITICAL\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="-65536" bold="true" italic="true" stripe="true"
```

HTH and YMMV...

Answer (score 7):

if you don't want to struggle much with regular expressions you can do an easy one

```
(INFO)
```

will match "INFO"
and you can do the rest for the other levels for a quick visualization.

Answer (score 5):

Had an issue on a very short test file - only four entries - and was searching forever why my correct pattern was not applied.

As the official docs state here
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/wiki/Custom-Log-Formats

**Selecting the right pattern**

"In order to detect the format of a log file, all existing patterns are matched against first 25 lines of a file. The one with most matches gets selected, if the amount of matches is above 5. Otherwise, a dumb per-line parser is used."

So if your log file is below 5 entries, the algorithm says it can not detect the correct pattern - and does not apply any pattern, even if there is only one active pattern and the regex works 100% fine.

**Groups**

"In addition, you must specify capture group indices for time, severity and category. Capture groups are numbered starting with 1. If you don't have a capture group for an item, specify 0."

Hence: Group Numbering starts at 1 !

##### My config

```
str_logging_format = "%(asctime)s - %(name)-12s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s"

# -- Ideolog Config --
# :pattern:
# ^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s-\s(\S*)\s*-\s(\w*)\s*-\s(.*)$
# :timePattern: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS
# :linePattern: ^\d
# :time Group : 1
# :severity Group : 3
# :Category Group: 2
#
# :highlighting:
# pattern="^\s*CRITICAL\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="FF0000" bold="true" stripe="true"
# pattern="^\s*ERROR\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="FF5F62" stripe="true"
# pattern="^\s*WARNING\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="C73EC8" bold="true"
# pattern="^\s*INFO\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="08C8EA"
# pattern="^\s*DEBUG\s*$" action="HIGHLIGHT_LINE" fg="3940C8"
```

PS: https://regex101.com/ is awesome to test your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

THis is for main.py

```
import logging as log
logger = r'logger.log'


if __name__ == "__main__":
log.basicConfig(filename=logger,
                format='%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=log.DEBUG)
```

and this is for highlighting (idealog)

```
message pattern:   ^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s(\S*)\s*(\w*)\s*(.*)$

message start pattern:    ^\d

time format         HH:mm:ss,SSS
time capture group:       0
severity capt group:      3
cat capt group:           1
```

I do that and all works. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kirill's answer I finally got it working in pycharm too. In case helpful, here is my setup.

My log file formatter is

```py
fmtter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s")
```

Typical lines of one of my log files look like this

```
2020-11-09 14:26:08,567-INFO-measuring Op/frame for CNN
2020-11-09 14:26:09,045-INFO-Op/frame: 249.64M
```

My message pattern is

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})-(\S*)-(.*)$
```

Note the explicit matching of entire date/time string, then '-', then level string, another '-', then rest of the line is the payload. The \S matches the level name with no spaces. The boost regexp page at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html is helpful and I used sublime to test the expression.

```
Time format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS
Time is group 0
Severity group 1
Category group 2
```